# C# HttpWebRequest - send huge stream to server

Tags: c#, http, stream

**UPD:** It turns out (from the code here https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Requests/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,1135 ) that `HttpWebRequest` does not support streaming, it collects data in memory and sends only on `GetResponse`.

So, will look into other options.

**Original question**

I have really huge stream, of unknown length (like "data from sensors"), that needs to be sent to server over HTTPS.

I am trying to use `HttpWebRequest` and send data using stream it provides.

Consdering the code below ("simulation" of large data to be sent), I expected `HttpWebRequest` to start sending data long before `r.GetResponse()`.

And either stream the data, or throw an Exception if the `https://some.url/endpoint`is unavailable, or has wrong certificate, or otherwise data cannot be sent.

However, what I get is exception that "Stream was too long".
Server never gets called.

What I am dowing wrong?
Should I somehow explicitly tell to `HttpWebRequest` to start communication?

The code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[64 * 1024];
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest r = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://some.url/endpoint");
                r.Method = "POST";
                r.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; // please do not do bufferring
                r.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                r.SendChunked = true;
                using Stream stream = r.GetRequestStream();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) // really, really large stream
                {
                    stream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                }
                var resp = r.GetResponse();
                // ...
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}"); // Stream was too long.
            }

        }
```

As requested in comments by @Jimi, full code snippet, `.Net Core 3.1`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace HttpWebRequestConsoleTest
{
    class ConsoleTest
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[64 * 1024];
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest r = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://some.invalid.url/endpoint");
                r.Method = "POST";
                r.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; // please do not bufferring
                r.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                r.SendChunked = true;
                using Stream stream = r.GetRequestStream();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) // really, really large stream
                {
                    stream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
                    //Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                var resp = r.GetResponse();
                // ...
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}"); // Stream was too long.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: Sounds like the web server doesn't allow requests that large. Are you in control of the web server? Can you increase the maximum size?

Comment: Server never gets called. The "Stream too long" exception is thrown even if to shut down the network at all.

Comment: Might be an Int32.MaxValue limit on the size of a stream allowed. Perhaps you can try bigger and smaller to see if this makes the difference?

Comment: `r.SendChunked = true;` (since you have `AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false`). You can use a FileStream and `CopyTo()` the request Stream.

Comment: @ekke Well... The stream should be, well, a stream. You write data to the stream, the server consumes, you write, server consumes. No length. That's how it should work, that's what I expected. If it keeps all data locally before sending - why using stream at all?..

Comment: @Jimi I do not have a file. ```r.SendChunked=true``` does not change how it behaves.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you have a file or not, that's just an example, I have no idea what you're sending. Since you set `AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false`, you either set the length of the Stream or send chunked, pick one.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for explanation. Anyway, ```r.SendChunked=true``` does not seem to help. As for length - it is unknnown. Setting to extra large value, like 60G, doesn't help either.

Comment: I doubt that after you have set `SendChunked = true` you have the same behavior. You may get a 405 (*Method not allowed*) or something else. For sure not a sudden termination (before any chunk of data is sent). -- If you have some other response, post the code that you're actually using, because this one looks like *pseudocode*, plus the .Net version you're targeting.

Comment: @Jimi added code, .net version and screenshot

Comment: Make a test with .Net Framework. If it succeeds, move to HttpClient in .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I've done it in the past.

When you want to send data where length is unknown, you have to send it chunked. There is no other way.

To test this, I set up a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and added this controller:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Utilities;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController, Produces("application/json"), Route("[controller]")]
    public sealed class StreamingController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("consumeStream"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConsumeStreamAsync()
        {
            using (var ns = new NullStream())
            {
                await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ns);
                return Ok(new { ns.Length });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, `NullStream` is an object that inherits from `System.IO.Stream` and simply tosses out data that is written to it, but keeps track of the length.

Here is the client-side code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44366/Streaming/consumeStream");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.SendChunked = true;
            req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
            req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            var buf = new byte[64 * 1024];
            using(var s = await req.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                for(long i = 0; i < 100_000_000; ++i)
                {
                    await s.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    if ((i & 10000) == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Wrote {i * buf.Length:n0} bytes...");
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync())
            using (var s = resp.GetResponseStream())
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(await sr.ReadToEndAsync());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness' sake, here is `NullStream`:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1.Utilities
{
    public sealed class NullStream : Stream
    {
        private long _length;
        public override bool CanRead => false;
        public override bool CanSeek => false;
        public override bool CanWrite => true;
        public override long Length => _length;
        public override long Position
        { 
            get => throw new NotImplementedException();
            set => throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override void Flush() { }
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override void SetLength(long value) =>
            _length = value;
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _length += count;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Write: {count:n0}; Length: {_length:n0}");
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the output:

```
...
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,222,022
Write: 57,344; Length: 4,514,279,366
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,344,902
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,410,438
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,475,974
Write: 57,344; Length: 4,514,533,318
Write: 61,440; Length: 4,514,594,758
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,660,294
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,725,830
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,791,366
Write: 65,536; Length: 4,514,856,902
...
```