# How to write bytes recorded with naudio to HTTP method

Tags: c#, .net-core, naudio

I'm new to `csharp`, and I want to make an audio streamming API.

I have one client app that use `naudio` to record audio from Windows microphone and send the recorded bytes to the server.

Here is how I'm sending the bytes to the server

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var addr = new Uri($"http://localhost:8080/api/stream");

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Post,
        addr
    );

    await httpClient.PostAsync(addr, new ByteArrayContent(data.Buffer));
}
```

In the server I have this `MemoryStream` that will receive the bytes

```cs
public static MemoryStream stream = new();
```

Here is how I get the bytes and write to the stream

```cs
[HttpPost("stream")]
public async Task<IActionResult> WriteStream()
{
    await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
    return Ok();
}
```

The final part is this `GET` method that will be consumed with HTML `<audio>` tag.

```cs
[HttpGet("stream")]
public IActionResult ReadStream()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "audio/wav");
    Response.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    
    while(true)
    {
        Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I want to send the recorded bytes here"));
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

But I don't know how to write the bytes in the response.

Comment: Don't create multiple `HttpClient` instances https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/ If you're going to pass chunks of audio buffers, http is a terrible protocol. Are you trying to stream audio in realtime? Or record and playback later?

Comment: This is very possible. I have answered similar questions in the past. Here is [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67240327/1204153).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, Yes, I'm trying to stream in realtime, I'm using HTTP just for learning, but the idea is to use UDP protocol. But I don't have a sample now.

Comment: I would recommend starting with something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-6.0 Note that you will need a strategy to handle jitter

Comment: A Request/Response data is HTML and binary data is not allowed.  You either have to convert to binary to a Base64 string or put the binary data into a MIME attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach to achieve this.

I'm using [Icecast](https://icecast.org) as streaming server, I've wrote my own implementation for Icecast TCP protocol and here is how I send the recorded bytes in `.ogg` format to the server.

```cs
// create the stream
var client = new TcpClient(endpoint.Host, endpoint.Port);
streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream) { AutoFlush = false };

// configure ogg encoder
var encoder = new OpusEncoder(SampleRate._48, 1, OpusApplication.OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP);
_recorder = new OpusOggWriteStream(encoder, streamWriter.BaseStream);

// _recorder is an OGG stream
OpusOggWriteStream? _recorder;

// start capturing
var captureDevice = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var devices = captureDevice.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.Active);
var deviceNumber = 0;

var waveIn = new WaveInEvent
{
    BufferMilliseconds = 50,
    DeviceNumber = deviceNumber,
    WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(SampleRate._48, 1)
};

waveIn.DataAvailable += (sender, data) => {
    var buff = new short[data.BytesRecorded / 2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(data.Buffer, 0, buff, 0, data.BytesRecorded);
    _recorder.WriteSamples(buff, 0, buff.Length);
};

waveIn.StartRecording();
```

And that's it, now I can listen for the recorded bytes with HTML `<audio>` tag