# Having an error uploading file to server using c# WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webclient

When I try to upload an specific huge file with the following code it throws an error on Webclient saying that “The Stream was too long”. How can I fix it? I’ve already tried using HttpClient.

With HttpClient the upload never ends.

Client-Side code:

```cs
private async Task UpdateFile(string filePath, string route) 
        {
            //System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
            Uri uri = new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress, relativeUri: route);//String.Format("{0}/api/TransferFiles/upload?loja={1}&name={2}", receiverUrl, loja, fi.Name));
            bool completed = false;
            using MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", UserSession.Token);
            client.UploadFile(uri, filePath);
           return;
        }
        class MyWebClient : WebClient
        {
            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
            {
                WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
                if (request is HttpWebRequest)
                {
                    (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
                }
                return request;
            }
        }
```

Here is the Server-Side code (The file has less than 3GB):

```cs
[RequestSizeLimit(10L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L)]
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 10L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L,ValueCountLimit =int.MaxValue)]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        [HttpPost("Upload/World")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {

            string token = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Authorization").Value;

            var details = await _authClient.UserDetailsAsync(token);
            if (!HasPermission(details))
                return Unauthorized();
            
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                // Handle the case where no file is uploaded
                return UnprocessableEntity(new MensagemDto("No file selected."));
            }
            if (file.Length > 4L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) // 4GB Validation
            {
                return UnprocessableEntity(new MensagemDto("File can't be 4GB or higher."));
            }

            try
            {
                // Specify a directory to save the uploaded file
                var uploadPath = Path.Combine(DirectoryHelper.GetBaseDirectory(), "uploads");

                if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
                }

                // Generate a unique file name to avoid overwriting existing files
                var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName+".zip";

                // Combine the upload path with the unique file name
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, uniqueFileName);

                // Copy the file to the specified path
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                var service = new SetupService();
                service.SetupWorld(details, filePath);

                return Ok("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions that occur during file upload
                return UnprocessableEntity(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions that occur during file upload
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Ps: the file has less than 3GB

Comment: You really should use HttpClient instead. Why didn't you show that attempt? And did that attempt get the exact same error?

Comment: The server may have a max size limit.  Try a smaller file and see if that works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# HttpWebRequest - send huge stream to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233672/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-send-huge-stream-to-server)

Comment: @mason With HttpClient the Upload never ends.

Comment: @jdweng I've added the server-side code. It has an 4GB Limit, but i'm sending an 2.1GB file

Comment: 4G Bytes or Bits?

Comment: WebClient is obsolete. Consider HttpClient. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185058/how-to-replace-obsolete-webclient-with-httpclient-in-net-6